# Recycler view in first result is different with scrolled design?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

everything in my recycler View work fine except this problem that when fragment start, first list that show in recycler View has problem with design and after scrolling it has been correct and repair that ! whats is the reason ?
this is my recycler view adapter :

```
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_list, container,
            false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    prepareMovieData();
```

and this it my XML rows for recycler:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="155dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:background="@color/WhiteColor"
tools:context="ir.himmel.visitors.himmel.LoginActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_finalPrice"
    android:layout_width="313dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/year"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_TimeOrder"
    tools:text="رقم کل سفارش: ۱۲۰۰۰۰ تومان" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_status"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:textColor="@color/year"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    tools:text="رقم کل سفارش: ۱۲۰۰۰۰ تومان" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="23dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/itemsicon"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"

    android:layout_width="420dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:textColor="@color/title"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="23dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/calendaricon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="23dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/pricesicon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/year"
    android:layout_width="313dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:textColor="@color/year"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_finalPrice"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tickicon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/GeneralBackGround"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_TimeOrder"

    android:layout_width="312dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />
```

this is result ! why does this behavior ?
as you show in first list result we have problem in design and after scrolling it repair by recycler View !

[image: this is first result that have problem :]

[image: after scroll it repaire design !]

Comment: at the end of your item xml, you have comment on <!--</LinearLayout>--> but you dont closing </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: No thats my mistake i forgot to select this iteml for copy correctly  !

Comment: Ok. I see you edited your post, are you closing your ConstraintLayout? </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: yes! of cource ! without it app cant build

Answer (score 1):

I also had such a problem once , solved it by adding these methods in the recyclerView adapter. What this does is that it reloads the rows even before it is visible ..

```
    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
        int wPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();   // if you need the position of current item else ignore..
        /* copy paste whatever you have in your onBindViewHolder method here */
     }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
         super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    /* copy paste whatever you have in your onBindViewHolder method here */

     }
```